# How to sum multiple results from a predicate in prolog?

Tags: prolog

So I have a predicate that sometimes returns more than one numerical result, eg.

```
X=3;

X=1
```

How can I sum multiple return values together? On occasion my predicate returns a single numerical value which is fine but if it returns more than one I want it to sum the multiple results together and output that rather than listing them separately.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didnt show us code so i cant tell exactly what is correct solution, but you can try with `findall/3` or `bagof/3` predicates to collect results in list and then sum them all.

Comment: Hmm ok thanks I'll have a look at those predicates and see if I can use them

Comment: @Cypher236 you'd use `findall/3` then `sumlist/2`.

Comment: @Cypher236 http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse49 here you have some tutorial about it.