# How to do the summation of numbers in different facts?

Tags: prolog

Let's say I have a game with a hero and several monsters. Each monster will give a certain amount of points if you defeat them.

```
total_score(Hero, Score):-
    defeated(Hero, Monster),
    score(Monster, Points),
    Score is Points.

monster(bat).
monster(skeleton).
monster(boss).

score(bat, 100).
score(skeleton, 100).
score(boss, 1000).

defeated(bob, bat).
defeated(bob, skeleton).
defeated(bob, boss).
```

If I do the future request :

```
?- total_score(bob, Y).
```

I would like the answer to be :

```
Y : 1200.
```

But I get instead :

```
Y : 100,
Y : 100,
Y : 1000.
```

What change should I make to total_score to make it work? I understand why I have this result, but I really don't know what to do to have a summation of facts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sum multiple results from a predicate in prolog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867950/how-to-sum-multiple-results-from-a-predicate-in-prolog)

Comment: @lurker Its true that this is a near duplicate, but this question is better quality and the answer there is also pretty vague (basically just pointing to the documentation), so I think it's ripe for a proper reply :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way of aggregating all the answers given by a goal is with `findall/3`. We can achieve your desired aim by modifying `total_score/2` thus:

```
total_score(Hero, Score):-
    findall(Points,
            ( defeated(Hero, Monster),
              score(Monster, Points)),
            Points),
    sum_list(Points, Score).
```

The [SWI-Prolog documentation for `findall/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3) sketches out the use of the predicate thus: `findall(+Template, :Goal, -Bag)`. I.e., we find all of the solutions that instantiate `Template` given a `Goal`, and these values are collected in the `Bag`. As you see from the example I provide, the goal can be a compound (i.e., a conjunction or disjunction).

However, SWI-Prolog also provides the (default, i.e., not needing explicit importation) [library(aggregate)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate), with which we avoid calling `sum_list/2`, thus:

```
total_score(Hero, Score):-
    aggregate_all( sum(Points),
                   ( defeated(Hero, Monster),
                     score(Monster, Points)),
                   Score).
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, I managed to find the solution, the thing is that I knew I could use findall and sum_list, but I didn't know how to join different relations together. I finally managed to find the solution after some research... So I did :

```
total_score(Hero, Score):-
    findall(Points, (defeated(Hero, Monster), score(Monster, Points)), ListOfPoints),
    sum_list(ListOfPoints, Score).
```