# Recursively finding sum in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to use Prolog to find a sum of a path using recursion. I need to pass a list of nodes of a graph, then have it return the sum of their weights.

This is what I've tried but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track.

```
connect(a,b,5).
connect(b,c,8).
connect(a,d,10).
connect(d,e,6).
connect(d,f,11).
connect(d,g,4).
connect(b,d,2).
connect(b,e,9).
connect(c,d,4).
connect(c,f,5).
connect(e,g,2).
connect(f,g,1).

list_sum([], 0).
list_sum([Head | Tail], TotalSum) :-    
   list_sum(connect(Head,Tail,X), Sum1),
   TotalSum is Head + Sum1.
```

Example goal:

```
list_sum([a,b,c],Sum).
Sum = 13
```

Comment: Your next question suggests that you answered this question on your own. You can either remove this question or add your answer to it.

Comment: This is closely related to this question: [How to sum multiple results froma predicate in Prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867950/how-to-sum-multiple-results-from-a-predicate-in-prolog).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three problems with your code. The first is that you have a logic variable X that you are not using, the second is that your predicate `list_sum` takes a **list** as its first element and yet you are giving it a **predicate** `connect(Head,Tail,X)`, the third is that you are using Head in an addition whereas apparently Head is an atom, not an *Integer* (maybe you meant X here), the fourth (I'm finding them as I go) is that the second argument of the predicate connect is an atom (representing a node, in this case) and you are giving it a list.

And a fifth problem with your question: you seem to think that the weights are on the **nodes** where they are clearly on the **edges**.

So I think the question of your assignment is two-folds:

1. Check that the path given to you is actually a path (in that there is a connection between each element and the next)
2. If it is indeed a path, sum the weights of your connections along the way.

In Prolog, the core artifact of programming are **predicates**, not **functions**. So to get the weight of a given link, you call `connect(Head,NextNode, Weight)`, which gives you (through unification) both the Weight and a possible NextNode, then the recursive call will check if that NextNode is indeed the next element in the list. After the recursive call, you use Weight instead of Head, and it should be a bit closer to the solution.

PS: Feel free to create a `list_sum_aux/3` and use it instead.